# Why are my controllers not working in Super Meat Boy on OS X?

Tags: macos, controllers, super-meat-boy

I'm trying to play Super Meat Boy on OSX using a joypad, and it doesn't work: the buttons are fine, but the D-pad is completely ignored!

I've tried many joypads and the result is the same for all of them. The only exception is a joypad with analog sticks, where the sticks are ignored but the d-pad works (I can't use that joypad for other reasons, though, and that's beside the point).

I've tried to make some random edits to `buttonmap.cfg` but nothing happened.

Comment: What kind of a controller?  Do you have a wired XBox 360 controller (or a PS3 controller with http://www.motioninjoy.com) available to test with?

Comment: No, I've tried a lot of normal PC usb controllers. I've also tried PS1 controllers (both with and without analog sticks) using an adapter.

Comment: Can you list the controller model(s) you have tried in the question?

Comment: @CyberSkull IIRC I've tried a PS2 controller, a PS1 controller with dual shock, and at least 4 different kinds of plain USB PC controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ControllerMate can help you ?
http://atmac.org/controllermate. If it sees your controller, you can remap your keyboard to it. Not a 100% sure it will work, but it may be worth trying..

Answer (score 0):

The Mac version of Super Meat Boy does not natively recognize controllers (at least in my personal experience with an Xbox 360 controller and the requisite drivers). You'll likely need to use a program like ControllerMate to map the controller to the keyboard.

Comment: Same with the Linux version... apparently.